# Detect CLICK even on href tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a confirm dialogue box on clicking an href link before processing. So I tried to trigger the click event on my link tag so that it displays the confirmation but its not working.

```
<span class="action-indicator" id="delete">
    <a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" width="auto" height="20" alt="" title="Delete Referral" /></a>
</span>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete a").click(function(){
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>?',
            buttons: {
                confirm: function () {

                },
                cancel: function () {
                    $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please have a look ! Help me why this is not working.

Comment: Are you using _jquery-confirm_ library ( http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ )

Comment: When you use a jQuery confirmation box the context moves on without you. That means that the return false prevents the link from firing and the user is displayed a confirmation. As far as I know the best you can do with this code is to then redirect the user to the same URL that the link was originally pointing to. If you use a native `confirm` call it will happen synchronously and you can choose to cancel the click event then.

Comment: yes I am using a jQuery confirm library and jQuery library both

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the redirect yourself in the confirm callback using `window.location`

```
$("#delete a").click(function(){
    // store href or reference to "this"
    var href = this.href;

    $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>?',
    buttons: {
    confirm: function () {
       // now do redirect
       window.location.href = href

    },
    cancel: function () {
      $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
    }
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: my problem is that its refreshing the page and not acting on the click to show the confirm dialogue

Comment: does the `<a>` exist when you run this...and are there errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to link [jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) library

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete a img").click(function(){
        $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to upgrade your membership to <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>?',
        buttons: {
        confirm: function () {

        },
        cancel: function () {
          $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
        }
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="action-indicator" id="delete">
 <a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" width="auto" height="20" alt="Delete" title="Delete Referral" /></a>
</span>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

And to make this work without the image, I added a value to the `alt` attribute.

Comment: @ShubhamJha OK, then I don't know why it isn't working for you, because adding that line made it working for me.

Comment: do u have a codepen or fiddle where u have made it working for u?

Comment: @ShubhamJha That code snippet included in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can give the onclick function inside this anchor tag itself. So you can write your own function inside this script tag like you used before(confirmation alert)! give a try!

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='return check()'>check</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function check()
{
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: this is 2017, not 1997. Modern day best practices are to use unobtrusive script

Comment: @charlietfl LOL this is simplest and easiest and above all... works

Comment: @GibralterTop so does external unobtrusive event listeners

Comment: @charlietfl Irrelevant. The answer works. If the reporter needs something a bit more robust or "clean", he/she can make their choice by selecting an answer. But down-voting a working answer is never the right call.

Comment: @GibralterTop it does nothing different that return false woudn't do in OP code